# Facebook insights not visible

Tags: facebook, statistics, facebook-insights

I am having some trouble with facebook insights and I was hoping someone could offer some help on this subject. The problem I am facing with is that no user (Role) that I have added to the Insights users for one of my applications doesn't see the application in the application dashboard and thus can't view the insights. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The users you have added as "Insights Users" in the "Roles" section of the App settings will get a notification which they have to confirm.
Clicking on the notification they will see a page describing how to get started as a developer, there is a yellow notification bar at the top of the page.
They need to click the link in it, which will open up the bar revealing a "Confirm" button.
After they have clicked that button, they can access the Insights under https://www.facebook.com/insights